# How to return a 403 on php file extension requests on Apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I get regularly script kiddies trying to wordpress hack their way into my rails applications.  I want Apache to return an immediate 403 and not pass the request to passenger for a 404.

Answer (score 3):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .*\.php - [R=403,L]
```

To also specify an error document:

```
RewriteRule .*\.php 403.html [R=403,L]
```

There are some [good examples](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/503-header-apache-htaccess/) of this.

Comment: The `403.html` in the second example will simply be ignored. To "specify an error document" you should use the `ErrorDocument 403 403.html` directive. (Or, remove the `R=403` flag on the `RewriteRule`... but you now have the additional task of manually sending the correct 403 status from the `403.html` file.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to place this rule just below `RewriteEngine` line:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.php[\s?/] [NC]
RewriteRule  ^ - [F]
```

Using `THE_REQUEST` here because `THE_REQUEST` variable represents original request received by Apache from your browser and **it doesn't get overwritten after execution of some rewrite rules**.